# How to specify non exact paths in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I currently have a statement as follows:

```
string dir = "C:\\Users\\Limited\\Desktop\\";
```

Although I would like it to be specified as a directory within the work directroy e.g.

workingpath/myfolder

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4):

I assumed you could just use a relative path, i.e. `"myfolder"`, but you can get and use the application path and append the subdirectory:

`string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);`

http://www.csharp-examples.net/get-application-directory/

Answer (score 1):

Just use the relative path to the application.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your path begins with a (drive letter or back)slash¹, it is interpreted as relative to the current working directory. So `"myfolder\\"` would be a relative directory.

¹In MS-DOS, and emulated by cmd.exe, it's possible to have a path relative to the current directory on another drive.

Answer (score 0):

```
const string subDir = "test_dir";
string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
string targetPath = Path.Combine(appPath, subDir);
```